# R: Remove rows with less than 20 non-"NA" values

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I remove all rows (from a data frame) that contains less than 20 non-"NA" values? I did try to look up a solution and tried different things, but I am not sure how to go about this.

(I apologize for not adding an example table, but I feel like its not really needed here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether you have pure numerical class or multiple classes across columns of your data frame `dat`, this will work.

```
IndexMat <- sapply(dat, is.na)
subset(dat, rowSums(!IndexMat) > 20)  ## or maybe `>=`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes sense! However I am getting "Error in !is.na : invalid argument type" when running the first command, but there is no error if I use "(dat, is.na)" Do you know why that is?